# How do I detect "the mode of redirection" using javascript?

Tags: javascript, redirect

During a browsing session, redirection usually occurs when,

1. user clicks on an anchor element,
2. user presses the reload button on browser,
3. user clicks on any element and execute a javascript redirection, using window.location properties,
4. programmatic (by javascript) redirection using window.location properties,

(There should be more)

I am trying to develop a javascript which I can classify them into two categories:
User-initiated and Programmatic.

I have tried a few prototypes but they aren't working.

Would anyone give me a hint?

Comment: I don't think this is easily possible, what do you want it for?

Comment: @deceze: with this  my understanding is that it is also not possible to detect browser back/forward button is that right ?

Comment: @Anil I think the best you can do is listen to `window.onunload`, but I don't see any way to discriminate *why* the window is being unloaded. So, yes.

Comment: @deceze, @Anil: I know the chance of making it work is minimal, but I still want to see if there is a good way for it.

I have tried comparing (original window.location) and (the new window.location) in window.onunload() or  window.onbeforeunload(), but they aren't working (i.e., giving me true all the time).

Comment: I think this can be done. But you will have to write click event for all anchor tags and use it in conjunction with a flag which holds the info that whether the click is initiated by user.